# How to create a bi-level (depth=1) bitmap file in java with embedded colour table and pixel colour indices?

Tags: java, image-processing, bmp

I am following, http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077561/learn-java/java-tip-60--saving-bitmap-files-in-java.html for bmp file creation through java.
I have googled on creating bi-level (ie.`depth =1`) image with color table, pixel color indices in java but not much helpful.
Any help on creating bi-level image with color table, pixel color indices in java would be highly appreciable!

Comment: Please post example code. And you can check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question,

Comment: Code formatting improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you refer to is quite old, and probably quite outdated.

You should be able to create a `BufferedImage` of type`TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`, with an `IndexColorModel` (containing the colours of your choice) and finally use `ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", file)` to write the resulting image to a BMP file.

If you want to learn about the BMP format in general, the [WikiPedia article on BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) is a very good resource.

Comment: Great Help! Thanks, Mr.Harald!

Answer (score 1):

As advised by Mr.Harald K, the following java code creates and writes bi-level images to file:

```
package imageprocessing;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class WriteBmpFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh_mm_ss");
        String path = "D:\\Project\\Images\\";
        String onlyBmpFileName = "Img_" + timeFormat.format(new Date());
        String bmpExtension = ".bmp";
        String bmpFilePath = path + onlyBmpFileName + bmpExtension;
        int imgRows = 32;
        int imgCols = 32;
        BufferedImage buffBiLevelImg = new BufferedImage(imgRows, imgCols, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        for (int r = 0; r <imgRows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < imgCols; c++) {
                if ((r + c) % 2 == 0) {
                    buffBiLevelImg.setRGB(r, c, Color.WHITE.getRGB());
                } else {
                    buffBiLevelImg.setRGB(r, c, Color.BLACK.getRGB());
                }
            }
        }


        try {
            ImageIO.write(buffBiLevelImg, "bmp", new File(bmpFilePath));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occured While Creating or Writing bitmap image ! and Stack trace is :\n " + ioe);
        }
    }
}
```